# Assign Country to IP addresses

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to join two table to get the country  code and ip address and have also attached table screenshot. How to join these two table? I am using Zeppelin

[image]

[image]

```
def ipToLong(dottedIP: String): Long = {
  val addrArray: Array[String] = dottedIP.split("\\.")
  var num: Long = 0
  var i: Int = 0
  while (i < addrArray.length) {
    val power: Int = 3 - i
    num = num + ((addrArray(i).toInt % 256) * Math.pow(256, power)).toLong
    i += 1
  }
  num
}

val rdd1 = sc.textFile("/user/mamta/mamta_audit/mamta_audit.csv")
case class IPCode(Date_key:String,LogID:String,Activity:String,SourceIP:String)
val sal1 = rdd1.map(_.split(",")).map(i => IPCode(i(0),i(1),i(2),i(3))).toDF("Date_key","LogID","Activity","SourceIP")



val rdd2 = sc.textFile("/user/mamta/IP_LocationCode.csv")
case class IPLoc(ip_from:String,
 ip_to:String,
Country_Code:String,
 Region_Name:String,
 City_Name:String
 )
 val sal2 = rdd2.map(_.split(",")).map(e => IPLoc(e(0),e(1),e(2),e(3),e(4))).toDF("ip_from","ip_to","Country_Code","Region_Name","City_Name")
```

I tried this but its giving me null value for ip_from, ip_to, countrycode

```
sal1.join(sal2,
     sal1("SourceIP") >= sal2("ip_from") && sal1("SourceIP") <= sal2("ip_to"), 
    "left"
).show()
```

Comment: Have you tried to use `sal1.join` yet?

Comment: Yes, I have tried but I don't know how to do casting in spark sql by using that IPv4toLong Function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `ipToLong` method needs to be converted to a `UDF` to be applied to the `IP` columns in your join conditions, as follows:

```
val sal1 = Seq(
  ("109.175.191.0"),
  ("invalid.ip"),
  ("187.42.62.209"),
  ("89.142.219.5")
).toDF("SourceIP")

val sal2 = Seq(
  ("75.0.0.0", "89.255.255.255", "Country A"),
  ("90.0.0.0", "129.255.255.255", "Country B"),
  ("130.0.0.0", "199.255.255.255", "Country C"),
  ("bad.ip", "bad.ip", "Country Z")
).toDF("ip_from", "ip_to", "country")

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

def ipToLongUDF = udf(
  (ip: String) => {
    val patternIPv4 = """\s*\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\s*""".r
    ip match {
      case patternIPv4() => ip.split("\\.").reverse.zipWithIndex.map(
          a => a._1.toInt * math.pow(256, a._2).toLong
        ).sum
      case _ => -1L
    }
  }
)

sal1.join(
    sal2,
    ipToLongUDF(sal1("SourceIP")) >= 0 &&
      ipToLongUDF(sal1("SourceIP")) >= ipToLongUDF(sal2("ip_from")) && 
      ipToLongUDF(sal1("SourceIP")) <= ipToLongUDF(sal2("ip_to")),
    "left"
  ).
  show
// +-------------+---------+---------------+---------+
// |     SourceIP|  ip_from|          ip_to|  country|
// +-------------+---------+---------------+---------+
// |109.175.191.0| 90.0.0.0|129.255.255.255|Country B|
// |   invalid.ip|     null|           null|     null|
// |187.42.62.209|130.0.0.0|199.255.255.255|Country C|
// | 89.142.219.5| 75.0.0.0| 89.255.255.255|Country A|
// +-------------+---------+---------------+---------+
```

Comment: I have edited my ipToLongUdF as yours and also using same join but I am getting error as org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 51.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 51.0 (TID 137, executor 29): java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "SourceIP"

Comment: The error message seems to indicate there were attempts to convert invalid IP address format.  Keep in mind the `ipToLong` method is for converting `IPv4` addresses, not [IPv6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6) which would require a different conversion method with IPv6-formatted `ip_to/ip_from` ranges.

Comment: not Sure but I have created a exactly same csv file for the sample as you have done in Seq. There are 2 csv file in which one contains Source IP and other ip_from, ip_to ,country.

Comment: Did you try using my sample data on just the CSV file with SourceIP field, or both CSV files?  From your sample data image, there seems to be IPv6 (e.g. 2001:4:ffff:ffff:...) addresses in your `ip_from/ip_to` fields.

Comment: I've added some IP address matching logic in the UDF to safeguard it from applying to `SourceIP` with invalid IPv4 format.

Comment: Thank you so much..I got it..You are the master..:)

Comment: Also added a non-negative `ipToLongUDF(SourceIP)` check in the join condition to cover cases in which `SourceIP` and `ip_from/ip_to` are invalid IPv4.